# Is instancing faster on GPU?

Tags: opengl

Is there any performance gain present when rendering instanced geometry in a GPU-limited application? Or is it all about draw calls?

Isn't it better to just bake all objects to a single VBO and render them with a single draw call? Assuming all objects are static and vertex memory is enough.

Comment: there is an optimal vertex count depending on hardware, but otherwise reducing draw calls is always a good choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If an instance model is small enough to *entirely* fit within the GPU's pre-T&L cache, then it can be a performance boost for the GPU. But unless that's the case, the GPU is going to have to read the same mesh data for each instance. So 1 instance repeated 200 times would have the same bandwidth cost as 200 separate meshes.

> Isn't it better to just bake all objects to a single VBO and render them with a single draw call?

No. Just because it's not necessarily gaining you on-GPU performance, that doesn't mean you should just ditch the whole thing. If instancing was appropriate for you, then you would have to be rendering the same mesh. So this "bake all objects" would be *repeating* the same mesh data. Once for every instance you intend to draw. Even if you don't save any read-time bandwidth, it's still hugely wasteful in memory.

Don't discount the importance of memory. Wasting memory can lead to runtime performance problems, as it can force textures out of GPU memory and cause thrashing.

Plus, it's less flexible. On one frame, you might only render 128 instances. On another, you might need 156. On another, you might only need 5. With your way, you have to keep around enough buffer storage to render some maximum number of instances. With actual instancing... you don't care.

And that doesn't even deal with how to get per-instance data. With instancing, you can either [use `gl_InstanceID`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Other_inputs) to read from some UBO/SSBO/texture array, or you use [instanced arrays](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Instance_Array), so that a vertex attribute is filled on a per-instance basis.

You can emulate `gl_InstanceID` with an extra integer attribute in your "bake all objects", but now you've made each vertex 4 bytes bigger. Emulating instanced arrays is a non-starter, since that would be hugely wasteful in memory.